# Use Regex in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Have a collection with values

```
_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd')
value:qwejc+iejtns/@
date:2019-12-13T07:09:40.075+00:00


_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd')
value:asdf+kine
date:2018-1-13T07:09:40.075+00:00
```

Need a required output :

grab data after `+`

```
_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd')
value:iejtns/@
date:2019-12-13T07:09:40.075+00:00


_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd')
value:kine
date:2018-1-13T07:09:40.075+00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$split` to split with `+` sign and then `$arrayElemAt` to get the last index.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "value": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [{ "$split": ["$value", "+"] }, -1]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ohIxPlLTEB)